# Use Lookup on associations that contain conditional statements

Tags: associations, conditional

I am using conditional statements in a list of rules to replace values in a vector of data. Since the same operation can be performed faster using Lookup on associations I would like to use this alternative procedure. However, I can not figure out how incorporate a conditional statement in an association but always receive output in the form of *Missing["KeyAbsent", data]*. Any tips how to achieve this?

Here is some example code and corresponding output:

```
(*Setting up the list of rules and corresponding association*)
assoc = <|1. -> "a", 2. -> "b", x_ /; x >= 3. -> "c"|>;
rule = {1. -> "a", 2. -> "b", x_ /; x >= 3. -> "c"};

(*Apply association and rule on data*)
data = {1., 3., 2., 4.};
dataRule = data /. rule
dataAssoc = Lookup[assoc, data]

Out[1]= {"a", 3., "b", "c"}
Out[2]= {"a", Missing["KeyAbsent", 3.], "b", Missing["KeyAbsent", 4.]}
```

I have consulted the documentation and searched the web about my issue but have not found an answer. Apologies should I have overlooked relevant information.

Every help is dearly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

There is a misunderstanding here. Associations are not replacement rules. Keys are never interpreted as patterns.  Associations are just a dictionary-like data structure that associates static values to static keys. The pattern in your association is treated like any other expression and is not used as a pattern, not even if you use this association with `ReplaceAll`.

If you are looking to speed up replacement rules, look at using [`Dispatch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) with `Replace[..., {1}]`, *not* `Association` with `Lookup`.

In your particular application, you may find the default value of `Lookup` (3rd argument) useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.